# Initialize LocalDateTime - with zero timings

Tags: java, jodatime

Which is the right way to `Initalize LocalDateTime - with zero timings`

I'm using a method `withTime(0, 0, 0, 0)` implementation would look like `new LocalDateTime().withTime(0, 0, 0, 0);`,

So my question is when dealing with `DayLight Savings` or `Timezone anamolies` would this way of initialization cause any issue. Or Is there any other options to avoid those issues.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why have you removed the `jodatime` tag? It is necessary in this case, because your current code does not use the Java8 `LocalDateTime` version.

Comment: You could achieve that by using `LocalDate` first, an then "make" it to a `LocalDateTime`: `LocalDate.now().atStartOfDay()`. But I can't tell for sure if this avoids the problems you've mentioned.

Comment: Yes.. you are right., but for ease of implementation, I am trring this.. 'cause in our code base we already having lots of conversion of one sort of `date form` to another `form`, So I prefer to go with `LocalDateTime`

Comment: `#atStartOfDay()` returns a `LocalDateTime`, so there is nothing you have to change in your code. But that method also takes care about the correct time, in this case midnight, and maybe also avoids the mentioned problems.

Answer (score 1):

If you stay within the scope of `LocalDateTime` then you will not get any problem with daylight savings or other timezone transitions. A `LocalDateTime` has no knowledge about timezone-related things. BUT:

If you convert any `LocalDateTime` to a `DateTime`-instance which has a reference to the global timeline then you can get a problem. Descriptions of the associated problems can be found in the [javadoc](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDate.html#toDateMidnight-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-). The reasons for the deprecation of some methods are also explained (**Brazil usually starts summer time at midnight so the creation of a `LocalDateTime` at midnight is not a problem but the creation of a `DateTime`**).

If you want to know how to safely convert a `LocalDateTime` (with any time component possibly falling in a gap) to a (global) `DateTime` then Joda-Time does not offer any conflict strategy, unfortunately. The [transition strategies](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/LocalDateTime.html#toDateTime-org.joda.time.DateTimeZone-) Joda-Time applies are fixed and not configurable:

> When the time zone is applied, the local date-time may be affected by
>   daylight saving. In a daylight saving gap, when the local time does
>   not exist, this method will throw an exception. In a daylight saving
>   overlap, when the same local time occurs twice, this method returns
>   the first occurrence of the local time.

However, some workaround for this limitation might be possible. You can for example ask the involved `DateTimeZone` if a given `LocalDateTime` [falls in a gap](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/DateTimeZone.html#isLocalDateTimeGap-org.joda.time.LocalDateTime-). Dependent on the answer of this query you can decide which offset you want to apply in order to convert to a `DateTime`.